# Log de erros do NUnit repetindo exceptions - Multiple failures or warnings in test

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Estou utilizando o NUnit para execução de scripts de teste com Selenium Webdriver em C# (Visual Studio). O projeto utiliza o template `Console Application`.

Ao executar, o projeto exibe um console (prompt) onde informo qual o ambiente de testes e quais scripts de teste serão executados em sequência (1 ou mais).

Durante a execução, caso um `Assert` do script de teste falhe, é gerado um arquivo de log `.txt` que grava a `exception` do erro. Então o próximo teste é executado, até concluir os testes da fila.

**Problema**: se outro teste da fila falhar, o NUnit lista novamente no log o erro do teste anterior mais o novo erro, e assim sucessivamente, enumerando os erros.

Log do Teste 1:

```
There are differences between the Test Dropdown List on the Report Template Editor page and the reference list

  Expected: True
  But was:  False
```

Log do Teste 2:

```
Multiple failures or warnings in test:

  1) The OK button was not visible to click on after 6 seconds

  Expected: True
  But was:  False

  2) There are differences between the Test Dropdown List on the Report Template Editor page and the reference list

  Expected: True
  But was:  False
```

Trecho que gera o arquivo de log:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("LogExecucao" + ".txt", true);

try
{
    //scripts de teste
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    sw.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

O mesmo problema foi reportado [neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639475/getting-a-list-of-failed-asserts-in-the-gauge-report-every-time-one-fails), mas não teve nenhuma resposta definitiva. No caso, o usuário utilizou a ferramenta *Gauge* da *Thoughtworks*:

Alguém da comunidade sabe uma forma de gravar as exceptions sem que o NUnit as repita?

Answer (score 0):

Sei que faz tempo que a pergunta foi feita mas achei interessante o tópico.

Creio que o erro deve ser por causa do Selenium Web Driver (+ NUnit). Fiz uma implementação simples de um console que tem um método que retorna uma exceção.

Se ocorresse o erro que menciona o meu arquivo de texto deveria ficar assim:

```
1
1
2
1
2
3
```

Mas ficou como esperado:

```
1
2
3
```

Segue print da minha implementação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS: Não consegui comentar na pergunta por não ter reputação no SO.